# How to align three columns, one is on left and the others on the right?

Tags: html, css

I have three div elements. I want the first one on the left, and the other on the right side.

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="first">1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>  
</div>
```

I tried flex style

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```

and for the first one I wanted the first one float to the left

```
.flex-container .first {
  float: left;
}
```

But they all float to the right. Please see the demo.

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ardmore/pen/GRNQxNO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.flex-container .first {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

`margin-right: auto;` will push it to the left, all the other elements will stay on the right.
In general, keep in mind that [Floats should not be used for layout](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2004/07/17/floats-dont-suck-if-you-use-them-right/). Float is meant to take an element, put it to one side, and let other contents flow around it. When you use Floats, you should use also [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container .first {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="first">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
 
</div>
```